# cat: 'd'$'\303''ata.txt': No such file or directory

Tags: docker, cat

I'm a newbie learning docker and have followed the instructions on docker homepage.
I'm following this tutorial at this [link](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/05_persisting_data/).
After, I have dragged the image to docker desktop completed as shown below:

[image]

Now, when I try to run the command as shown in the tutorial, I get an error:

```
cat: '/d'$'\303''ata.txt': No such file or directory
```

[image]

I'm sure I followed the instructions from start to finish and it worked perfectly but on this example I get an error.
Can someone explain it to me and show me how to fix it?

Comment: I think you did not run the previous command to create the data.txt file, try do it again.

Comment: but I found the data.txt file in this container

Comment: Did you copy-past the `cat /data.txt` command from the webpage? This looks as if there are some non-printable characters between `d` and `ata.txt`. Can you try to type the command by hand?

Comment: no, I also tried entering the command by hand but the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I have the answer for this error. That's because on my computer I'm using Unikey for Vietnamese (This is the most popular Vietnamese typing program on Windows in Vietnam)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ3zP.png)
This is the main cause of this error, I fixed it by turning off Unikey Vietnamese and re-entering the command as in the website's instructions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd0e3.png)